# flask app won't run on ubuntu 12.04 (digital ocean)

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am having difficulties deploying a basic flask app on a digital ocean server running ubuntu 12.04, apache2, and mod-wsgi.  I have tried a number of different modifications of both the myapp.conf file and the myapp.wsgi file.  I suspected that these were the culprits, but now I'm not so sure.

At **all times**, visiting my url just displays the apache 'It works' dialogue. Each attempt made to successfully restart the apache service (after trying to fix the problem), and access the website sees this **same** activity in the error.log:

```
[Wed Aug 27 00:49:14 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Aug 27 00:49:15 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

And this activity in the access.log:

```
11.22.33.44 - - [27/Aug/2014:00:49:19 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"
11.22.33.44 - - [27/Aug/2014:00:49:21 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 208 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"
11.22.33.44 - - [27/Aug/2014:00:49:24 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 208 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"
```

By 'basic' flask app, I mean: no sql database (as in none, not as in non-relational), no site users, no factory, no blueprint, etc.

The relevant directory /var/www/myapp/ looks like this (using virtualenv to run the app):

```
myapp/
  + myapp/
  |    + static/
  |    + templates/
  |    + venv/
  |    | __init__.py
  | myapp.wsgi
```

Although I have tried several versions of the myapp.conf file, these two are representative:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myapp.com
        WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=flask group=www-data home=/var/www/myapp/
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/myapp/myapp/>
            WSGIProcessGroup myapp
            WSGIApplicationGroup % {GLOBAL}
            WSGIScriptReloading On
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myapp.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi

        <Directory /var/www/myapp/myapp/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/myapp/myapp/static
        <Directory /var/www/myapp/myapp/static/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The two general types of myapp.wsgi files I have tried are:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/myapp/")

from myapp import app as application
```

And:

```
activate_this = '/var/www/myapp/myapp/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

import os
import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/myapp/')

from myapp import app as application

#commenting out same in __init__.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

The app does run successfully on my local machine, and I always chowned the /var/www/ directory for each user identified in the .conf file.

Any thoughts, tips, pointers, etc are extraordinarily welcome.  Thanks very kindly.

Comment: How have you told Apache to use the VirtualHost configuration in myapp.conf. Are there any other VirtualHost's set up for the same server, especially with same ServerName.

Comment: And the directory given to ``Directory`` directive is wrong unless that is due to your attempts to obfuscate real values. It would have nothing to do though with why VirtualHost being ignored.

Comment: Also mod_wsgi disallows doing anything with sys.stdout and sys.stderr. (Which your logger is writing to). See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Comment: I am totally with you, but it appears as if the Virtual Host is being loaded correctly, but the application isn't being initialized for incoming requests.. I think.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton the directory in the question is obfuscated, but represents how I've formed it.  What is wrong in the directory in the example? Thanks.

Comment: There was never any restrictions on stderr in mod_wsgi so the documentation on that point is wrong and loggers set up to use stderr would always work. The comment about stdout is also woefully out of date and should be removed from the documentation. The default of restricting stdout to try and get you to write portable WSGI applications was removed 5 years ago.

Comment: The directory given by the Directory directive should be the directory the WSGI script file is in to allow access to the WSGI script file. So '/var/www/myapp' and not '/var/www/myapp/myapp'.

Comment: Ok, I'll try.  Annoying that that conflicts with this documentation: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps